# Simply Gallery: Change color of title in just one block

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, gallery

Am using SimpLy Gallery to showcase different services I offer to clients. Each service has a different color assigned to it. You can set the global title text color (which i have to white) and it works well, except over one of the blocks which is yellow. Am struggling finding a way to make that particular text black. As far as i can see, the text on all boxes has to be the same color. How can i change only one text?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9WgP.png)

http://emena.online/#Portafolio

I tried going to inspect mode on chrome, but if i change the color on one, it changes the color on all. I´ve looked through the plugins settings with no luck (it´s set to global) and finally I´ve tried to insert css to the title and it breaks the whole plugin. I just which to change color on two words "Web Design".

PD: Each gallery has it´s own shortcode and you can add additional css through the plugins interface.

Comment: Hello bro, check this screenshot (you want to this type)
https://prnt.sc/tvalT6orA029 
(Add this css)
.pgcsimplygalleryblock-albums-cover:nth-child(3) .pgcsimplygalleryblock-albums-title{color: red;}